# mysql display results for every month with result as 0 based on joins

Tags: mysql

My original query is like this which gets total records and then groups by corresponding year and month for a particular fiscal year.

```
`SELECT s.field_source_target_id AS field_source_target_id, tfd.name AS name, tfdc.name AS tfdc_name,
       tfdr.name AS tfdr_name, max(nfcd.field_creation_date_value) AS Monat,
       COUNT(DISTINCT nfd.nid) AS IntpM, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(26) then 1 else 0 end) AS IGVB, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(27) then 1 else 0 end) AS IGDG, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(30) then 1 else 0 end) AS PTVB,SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(31) then 1 else 0 end) AS PTDG,SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(28) then 1 else 0 end) AS VGVB, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(29) then 1 else 0 end) AS VGDG,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case WHEN st.field_status_target_id in(33,34,35) then nfd.nid else null end) AS Onboard
FROM
  node_field_data nfd
  INNER JOIN node__field_region r ON r.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN node__field_source s ON s.entity_id = nfd.nid
  left JOIN node__field_creation_date nfcd ON nfcd.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data tfd ON tfd.tid = s.field_source_target_id
  INNER JOIN node__field_status st ON st.entity_id = nfd.nid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN node__field_onboard_vpkn vpkn ON vpkn.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN node__field_channel nfc ON nfc.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data tfdr ON tfdr.tid = r.field_region_target_id
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data tfdc ON tfdc.tid = nfc.field_channel_target_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN node__field_doings doing ON doing.entity_id = nfd.nid
WHERE
      (type = 'candidate') AND (status = 1)
GROUP BY tfd.name, tfdc.name, tfdr.name, r.field_region_target_id, s.field_source_target_id,
  YEAR(nfcd.field_creation_date_value), MONTH(nfcd.field_creation_date_value)

ORDER BY s.field_source_target_id ASC,tfdr_name ASC`
```

The result looks like

```
83,SEA,KMU,R1,2018-08-07,1
83,SEA,KMU,R2,2018-05-23,2
83,SEA,KMU,R2,2018-06-20,1
83,SEA,KMU,R2,2018-07-17,2
```

Now i want to query for records which is in node__field_creation_date table joined with other tables for every source in for every month for every channel and for every region . What I tried so far

```
    SELECT  allmonths.m,nfcd.field_creation_date_value,MONTH(nfcd.field_creation_date_value) as month
  ,s.field_source_target_id AS field_source_target_id, tfd.name AS name, tfdc.name AS tfdc_name,
  tfdr.name AS tfdr_name, max(nfcd.field_creation_date_value) AS Monat,
  COUNT(DISTINCT nfd.nid) AS IntpM, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(26) then 1 else 0 end) AS IGVB, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(27) then 1 else 0 end) AS IGDG, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(30) then 1 else 0 end) AS PTVB,SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(31) then 1 else 0 end) AS PTDG,SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(28) then 1 else 0 end) AS VGVB, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(29) then 1 else 0 end) AS VGDG,
  COUNT(DISTINCT case WHEN st.field_status_target_id in(33,34,35) then nfd.nid else null end) AS Onboard
FROM (
    SELECT 01 as m UNION SELECT 2 as m UNION SELECT 03 as m UNION SELECT 04 as m UNION SELECT 5 as m UNION SELECT 6 as m
    UNION SELECT 7 as m UNION SELECT 8 as m UNION SELECT 09 as m UNION SELECT 10 as m UNION SELECT 11 as m UNION SELECT 12 as m
  ) as allmonths
  left JOIN node__field_creation_date nfcd ON MONTH(nfcd.field_creation_date_value) = allmonths.m
  LEFT JOIN node_field_data nfd ON nfd.nid = nfcd.entity_id
  INNER JOIN node__field_region r ON r.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN node__field_source s ON s.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data tfd ON tfd.tid = s.field_source_target_id
  INNER JOIN node__field_status st ON st.entity_id = nfd.nid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN node__field_onboard_vpkn vpkn ON vpkn.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN node__field_channel nfc ON nfc.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data tfdr ON tfdr.tid = r.field_region_target_id
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data tfdc ON tfdc.tid = nfc.field_channel_target_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN node__field_doings doing ON doing.entity_id = nfd.nid
WHERE
  (nfcd.field_creation_date_value BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2019-03-31') AND
       (type = 'candidate') AND (status = 1)
GROUP BY tfd.name, tfdc.name, tfdr.name, r.field_region_target_id, s.field_source_target_id,
  allmonths.m
#   ,YEAR(nfcd.field_creation_date_value), MONTH(nfcd.field_creation_date_value)
ORDER BY s.field_source_target_id ASC
  ,tfdc_name,tfdr_name,Monat ASC;
```

I want something like

```
83,SEA,KMU,R1,2018-08-07,1
83,SEA,KMU,R2,2018-05-23,2
83,SEA,KMU,R2,2018-04-23,0 // missing month with 0 records
83,SEA,KMU,R2,2018-06-20,1
83,SEA,KMU,R2,2018-07-17,2
```

Result i get is the same as above query..Anybody would like to help me?

Comment: What about Cross join instead of Left Join.

Comment: You mean  CROSS JOIN node__field_creation_date nfcd ON MONTH(nfcd.field_creation_date_value) = allmonths.m ? I tried and is the same story

Answer (score 0):

Shift `(nfcd.field_creation_date_value BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2019-03-31')` from your `WHERE` clause to the **Left Join** condition (`ON` clause).

Because of this condition being in where, it is ignoring the cases where `nfcd.field_creation_date_value` is `null`; hence you are not getting the results with missing month.

Do the following instead:

```
SELECT  allmonths.m,nfcd.field_creation_date_value,MONTH(nfcd.field_creation_date_value) as month
  ,s.field_source_target_id AS field_source_target_id, tfd.name AS name, tfdc.name AS tfdc_name,
  tfdr.name AS tfdr_name, max(nfcd.field_creation_date_value) AS Monat,
  COUNT(DISTINCT nfd.nid) AS IntpM, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(26) then 1 else 0 end) AS IGVB, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(27) then 1 else 0 end) AS IGDG, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(30) then 1 else 0 end) AS PTVB,SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(31) then 1 else 0 end) AS PTDG,SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(28) then 1 else 0 end) AS VGVB, SUM(case WHEN doing.field_doings_target_id in(29) then 1 else 0 end) AS VGDG,
  COUNT(DISTINCT case WHEN st.field_status_target_id in(33,34,35) then nfd.nid else null end) AS Onboard
FROM (
    SELECT 01 as m UNION SELECT 2 as m UNION SELECT 03 as m UNION SELECT 04 as m UNION SELECT 5 as m UNION SELECT 6 as m
    UNION SELECT 7 as m UNION SELECT 8 as m UNION SELECT 09 as m UNION SELECT 10 as m UNION SELECT 11 as m UNION SELECT 12 as m
  ) as allmonths
  left JOIN node__field_creation_date nfcd ON MONTH(nfcd.field_creation_date_value) = allmonths.m AND (nfcd.field_creation_date_value BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2019-03-31')  
  LEFT JOIN node_field_data nfd ON nfd.nid = nfcd.entity_id
  INNER JOIN node__field_region r ON r.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN node__field_source s ON s.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data tfd ON tfd.tid = s.field_source_target_id
  INNER JOIN node__field_status st ON st.entity_id = nfd.nid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN node__field_onboard_vpkn vpkn ON vpkn.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN node__field_channel nfc ON nfc.entity_id = nfd.nid
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data tfdr ON tfdr.tid = r.field_region_target_id
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data tfdc ON tfdc.tid = nfc.field_channel_target_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN node__field_doings doing ON doing.entity_id = nfd.nid
WHERE
  (type = 'candidate') AND (status = 1)
GROUP BY tfd.name, tfdc.name, tfdr.name, r.field_region_target_id, s.field_source_target_id,
  allmonths.m
#   ,YEAR(nfcd.field_creation_date_value), MONTH(nfcd.field_creation_date_value)
ORDER BY s.field_source_target_id ASC
  ,tfdc_name,tfdr_name,Monat ASC;
```

Comment: tried this and it is returning the same result, would love to hear any other updates

Comment: @Unni in that case you will need to create a sql fiddle with some sample data to play with. With such a big query, and no idea of values in the tables, it is hard to figure out what is wrong!

Comment: Agreed .. this is drupal and it has its own complexities and i will try to create a fiddle since its so timeconsuming...do you have any quick correction on the union part?

Comment: @Unni shouldn't it be `1` instead of `01`. likewise for all the values

Comment: tried both.it always sticks to the same result count. i doubt there is any problem with group by or maybe join?

Comment: @Unni I think if you can try to get a bare minimum sql fiddle out. Then, something can be worked out. Otherwise as of now it's just guesswork

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2s8kZ495WdaYibCGPVZf9Z/0.. Fiddle i created

Comment: @Unni need to put in data also :-)

Comment: sorry forgot to update the fiddle ..You can check it now

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2s8kZ495WdaYibCGPVZf9Z/1 Can you please try  updated version with 1 instead of 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180871/discussion-between-unni-and-madhur-bhaiya).